# TFS 2017 Test Task Version 2 unable to get Feature Flag warnings

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2017, tfsbuild, vstest

Recently started getting the following warnings from my VsTest task *Version 2* (Version 1 does NOT produce the warnings) after the build machine completes a (TFS2017) build:

```
Unable to get feature flag: TestExecution.EnableTranslationApi
Unable to get feature flag: TestExecution.EnableDiagnostics
```

I created a simple build definition that has a VsTest task, but doesn't even have any tests and i get the same issue.  Here's its  log:

```
2019-05-15T17:42:14.4932509Z ##[section]Starting: VsTest - testAssemblies
2019-05-15T17:42:14.4943225Z ==============================================================================
2019-05-15T17:42:14.4943357Z Task         : Visual Studio Test
2019-05-15T17:42:14.4943570Z Description  : Run unit and functional tests (Selenium, Appium, Coded UI test, etc.) using the Visual Studio Test (VsTest) runner. Test frameworks that have a Visual Studio test adapter such as MsTest, xUnit, NUnit, Chutzpah (for JavaScript tests using QUnit, Mocha and Jasmine), etc. can be run. Tests can be distributed on multiple agents using this task (version 2).
2019-05-15T17:42:14.4943768Z Version      : 2.145.0
2019-05-15T17:42:14.4943871Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-05-15T17:42:14.4943976Z Help         : [More information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=835764)
2019-05-15T17:42:14.4944089Z ==============================================================================
2019-05-15T17:42:21.2906431Z SystemVssConnection exists true
2019-05-15T17:42:21.3711041Z ##[warning]Unable to get feature flag: TestExecution.EnableTranslationApi
2019-05-15T17:42:21.5124738Z SystemVssConnection exists true
2019-05-15T17:42:21.5301824Z ##[warning]Unable to get feature flag: TestExecution.EnableDiagnostics
2019-05-15T17:42:21.6498462Z Running tests using vstest.console.exe runner.
2019-05-15T17:42:21.6608055Z ======================================================
2019-05-15T17:42:21.6783692Z Test selector : Test assemblies
2019-05-15T17:42:21.6811412Z Test filter criteria : null
2019-05-15T17:42:21.7076165Z Search folder : D:\Agent02\_work\5\s
2019-05-15T17:42:21.8323849Z VisualStudio version selected for test execution : latest
2019-05-15T17:42:25.9981965Z Run in parallel : false
2019-05-15T17:42:25.9982368Z Run in isolation : false
2019-05-15T17:42:25.9982730Z Path to custom adapters : null
2019-05-15T17:42:25.9983384Z Other console options : null
2019-05-15T17:42:25.9983727Z Code coverage enabled : false
2019-05-15T17:42:25.9983845Z Diagnostics enabled : false
2019-05-15T17:42:25.9984208Z SystemVssConnection exists true
2019-05-15T17:42:25.9985363Z Run the tests locally using vstest.console.exe
2019-05-15T17:42:25.9985487Z ========================================================
2019-05-15T17:42:25.9985644Z Test selector : Test assemblies
2019-05-15T17:42:25.9985820Z Test assemblies : **\release\*test*.dll,!**\obj\**
2019-05-15T17:42:25.9985973Z Test filter criteria : null
2019-05-15T17:42:25.9986123Z Search folder : D:\Agent02\_work\5\s
2019-05-15T17:42:25.9986291Z Run settings file : D:\Agent02\_work\5\s
2019-05-15T17:42:25.9986492Z Run in parallel : false
2019-05-15T17:42:25.9986654Z Run in isolation : false
2019-05-15T17:42:25.9988401Z Path to custom adapters : null
2019-05-15T17:42:25.9988814Z Other console options : null
2019-05-15T17:42:25.9989201Z Code coverage enabled : false
2019-05-15T17:42:25.9989420Z Diagnostics enabled : false
2019-05-15T17:42:25.9990350Z Rerun failed tests: false
2019-05-15T17:42:25.9990938Z VisualStudio version selected for test execution : latest
2019-05-15T17:42:26.0399542Z ========================================================
2019-05-15T17:42:32.5917477Z ##[warning]No test assemblies found matching the pattern: **\release\*test*.dll,!**\obj\**.
2019-05-15T17:42:32.5917841Z ======================================================
2019-05-15T17:42:32.7510424Z ##[section]Finishing: VsTest - testAssemblies
```

What is this warning trying to tell me, and how can i fix it?

Comment: This is still happening in VS2019 BTW

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Never have seen any responses to fix this, still happening...

Comment: Appears to be known issue and the official solution is to ignore it: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/15006#issuecomment-888115400